# Household vehicle ownership allocation based on vehicle sales data

Tags: logistic, random-forest, multinomial-logit

I have a household travel survey data, which consisted of the number of vehicle owned for each of the household, household income, job, and household size. However, the data didn't show the brand, engine size, and types (SUV, sedan) of the vehicles that is owned by the household. I have another data that shows the brand, engine size, and types, derived from a national car sales data. Hence, I'd like to estimate the vehicle type, brand, etc. owned by each of the household. What method should I use? Random assignment, multinomial logit, or any preferences?

Thanks a lot before

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done, because you don't have relevant information. What you want to do is a kind of SQL `LEFT JOIN`, but you don't have shared keys between the two datasets. In such a case, the datasets cannot be combined. It could be done if you had a third dataset, containing the same keys (or a subset of it) as both your datasets, so you could use it to learn the mapping and apply it to your data. Otherwise, it is just guessing.